# how to provide a value for an imported embedded struct literal?

Tags: go

noob here :)
i'm having trouble understanding

when i do this in one file:

`scratch.go`

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type foo struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
}

type bar struct {
    foo
    field3 string
    field4 string
}

func main() {
    fooBar := bar{
        foo{
            "apples",
            "banana",
        },
        "spam",
        "eggs",
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", fooBar)

}
```

it works
but when i have 3 files like this

```
rootproject
├── magazine
│   ├── address.go
│   └── employee.go
└── main.go
```

`magazine/address.go`

```golang
package magazine

type Address struct {
    Street     string
    City       string
    State      string
    PostalCode string
}
```

`magazine/employee.go`

```golang
package magazine

type Employee struct {
    Name   string
    Salary float64
    Address
}
```

and
`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "magazine"
)

func main() {
    employee := magazine.Employee{
        Name:   "pogi",
        Salary: 69420,
        magazine.Address{
            Street:     "23 pukinginamo st.",
            City:       "bactol city",
            State:      "betlog",
            PostalCode: "23432",
        },
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", employee)

}
```

it's error :(

```
mixture of field:value and value elements in struct literal
```

i don't get it, what am i doing wrong? i thought if the struct was nested it is said to be embedded in the outer struct and i can access the the fields of the inner struct from the outer one. which is the case for my first example(the singular file), but when i do it within packages. it's different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i thought if the struct was nested it is said to be embedded in the outer struct and i can access the the fields of the inner struct from the outer one.

Yes, you can access an embedded field's members directly, however that does not apply when constructing the struct with a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals). If you look through the rules for struct literals you'll find this one:

> If any element has a key, every element must have a key.

This rule applies regardless of whether a field is embedded or not.

---

To fix the error you can either remove the other keys:

```golang
func main() {
    employee := magazine.Employee{
        "pogi",
        69420,
        magazine.Address{
            Street:     "23 pukinginamo st.",
            City:       "bactol city",
            State:      "betlog",
            PostalCode: "23432",
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", employee)
}
```

Or you can specify all the keys:

```golang
func main() {
    employee := magazine.Employee{
        Name:   "pogi",
        Salary: 69420,
        Address: magazine.Address{
            Street:     "23 pukinginamo st.",
            City:       "bactol city",
            State:      "betlog",
            PostalCode: "23432",
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", employee)
}
```

Note that for an embedded field you can use the type's unqualified name to refer to the embedded field.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name `T` or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not be a pointer type. **The unqualified type name acts as the field name**.

Comment: yup that worked ty but why did it not need that field name in the first example? the singular file

Comment: I've updated the answer, it should now explain that as well. But the reason is that that's because you haven't specified the other keys either.

Comment: So, just in case it's not clear, this basically has nothing to do with single file / multi file. You were using "no keys" in the single file, while in the multi file you were using a mixture of keys-and-no-keys in the literal and that's not allowed.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/k3FWOF4ZTcF